# Testing frameworks for tezos smart-contracts

Tags: smart-contracts, testing, ligo

I  did few smart contracts with Ligo, but now looking for more productionize setup.

1. Is there a test framework one can use for Tezos? I'm looking for something like `waffle` + `mocha` in Ethereum, or `truffle`. I could do it myself with `mocha` and [taquito](https://tezostaquito.io) or [ConseilJS](https://cryptonomic.github.io/ConseilJS), but firstly want to check if there are ready frameworks.
2. Is there a lite version of a Tezos node? Something like `ganache`, something to super easily start and use to execute smart-contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the preview version of `truffle` tools for working with smart contacts in Tezos:
https://www.trufflesuite.com:8443/docs/tezos/truffle/quickstart

Answer (score 6):

Ad 1. I am not sure whether it is what you look for, but look at: https://smartpy.io/demo/

SmartPy offers different tools:

1. Analytics: elements of the UI in SmartPy.io to analyse smart
   contracts and their properties;
2. SmartML: a virtual machine written in OCaml;
3. Compiler: used to translate contracts from SmartML to Michelson;
4. Python library: facilitates the use of SmartML definitions.

Comment: Thanks for tip. But, does this require writing smart-contracts in Python? I would prefer to stick with Ligo.

Comment: Here is a link go Ligo playground: https://ide.ligolang.org but the IDE does not have Waffle features, yet ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Tezster-CLI for setting up local environment and use Tezster-Bundle to develop,deploy and test your contracts.

Tezster-CLI: https://github.com/Tezsure/Tezster-CLI

Tezster-Bundle: https://github.com/Tezsure/Bundle-react